# Getting Window of Event Sender

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class that allows the user to open new windows of type `RandomWindowType`. I then have event handlers in that class that detect if a selection changed. When I get back this information I perform an action depending on the selection. However, I would like to know in which window the object has undergone the selection change. Is there some way I can get this information from the sender? If not maybe I can get the active window and cast it to `RandomWindowType` ?

**Code**

```
void treeListControl1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Which window?
   // Take action
}
```

Comment: sender as RandomWindowType will give you the window wich triggered the event.

Comment: I think you have attached event to treeListControl & not to a window.In this case you need to get the parent window of the control I think.Is this what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cast sender to your window type to get it:

```
void treeListControl1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var window = sender as RandomWindowType;
    if (window == null)   // if it's not your random type
      return;
    // Take action
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks! C# can be kind of Swift-esque sometimes